# Multiple players on Xbox Minecraft Online game when only one has Xbox Live?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network, minecraft-legacy-console

Picture this:
Me and three others are playing Minecraft.
I have Xbox Live Gold.
Three more players on the same console don't.

Is it possible to play an online game (with another console of mine), when only one player has Xbox Live Gold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do believe this is possible. If you sign in with the account that has gold on "xbox B" and set it as your home xbox, then actually play with the gold account on "xbox A", everybody should be able to play together over xbox live with one the one gold account.

[See this post](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/691088-xbox-one/71210220)

In the following link, which provides more info about gold sharing on the Xbox One, consider your home xbox to be "xbox B" in this case, and the friend's xbox on the page to be "xbox A".

[More information on Gold Sharing](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/xbox-live/xbox-live-gold-sharing-features)

Comment: Note that this only work with guest accounts

Comment: @Riley Does it? I wasn't aware. I know if using multiple gamertags on the console none of them have to be guest, my gamertag has gold on it and my daughters each have their own non-gold accounts, but are able to play online because it's sharing my gamertags gold subscription.

Comment: Hm, turns out it changed then. It used to be like this. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @Riley No problem! I did add an additional link to the answer, though, which provides a little more information.